# Can't find extensions to add redis as destination mirth connector

Tags: redis, mirth

I am new in mirth connector and want to publish message after processing of hl7 file. I tried to find extension for redis but couldn't find anything.

Can anyone help to find redis extension for mirth connector?

Comment: There is none. You may create your own (which will not run under default Mirth installation due to signed certificates) or use Redis as an object in JavaScripts connector.

Comment: i don't know about `redis`, but you can create your own program which work dynamically, and convert that project into `JAR`, and import that custom jar into `Setting>Resources>` and may be your problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you have to do through custom code. The easiest solution that I would do is to download the redis java client. From here you can bring in the jar and reference it inside of javascript connector.

To solve this take a look at:
https://redislabs.com/lp/redis-java/ 
Use this documentation for how to reference the specific redis methods

and

[Mirth connect to mongo db connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271713/mirth-connect-to-mongo-db-connectivity)
Use this documentation for how to reference external libraries in Mirth connect.

This should give you all that you need to solve the issue.