# NextGen (Mirth) Connect & MongoDB java driver error

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, driver, mirth

I am trying to configure Mirth Connect Server 3.10.1 (Java version: 1.8.0_181), to write FHIR JSON docs to MongoDB. I've followed instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271713/mirth-connect-to-mongo-db-connectivity) and have these drivers in `custom-lib/`

- bson-4.2.0.jar
- mongodb-driver-3.9.1.jar
- mongodb-driver-core-4.2.0.jar

My `conf/dbdrivers.xml` has an entry like this,

```
<driver class"org.mongodb.Driver" name="MongoDB" template="mongodb://localhost:27017/" selectLimit="" />
```

I've setup my Channel Destination with a `JavaScript Writer` Connector Type and used this JS,

```
var mongoClient = new Packages.com.mongodb.MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
var database = mongoClient.getDatabase("synthea");
var collection = database.getCollection("synthea");                   
var jsonDoc = JSON.stringify(connectorMessage.getEncodedData(msg));
var doc = Packages.org.bson.Document.parse(jsonDoc);

collection.insertOne(doc);
var myDoc = collection.find().first();
logger.debug(myDoc.toJson());

mongoClient.close();

return;
```

When I deploy the Channel, I am getting this error.

Can anyone tell me what this means?

Any help or guidance very much (and humbly) appreciated.

```
JavaScript Writer error
ERROR MESSAGE: Error evaluating JavaScript Writer
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder.maxWaitQueueSize(int)'
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions.<init>(MongoClientOptions.java:149)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions.<init>(MongoClientOptions.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions$Builder.build(MongoClientOptions.java:1612)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:155)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:145)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor135.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.newInstance(MemberBox.java:171)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.constructInternal(NativeJavaClass.java:268)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.constructSpecific(NativeJavaClass.java:207)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.construct(NativeJavaClass.java:169)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1713)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1009)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:109)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:412)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3545)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:121)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.executeScript(JavaScriptTask.java:150)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.js.JavaScriptDispatcher$JavaScriptDispatcherTask.doCall(JavaScriptDispatcher.java:230)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.js.JavaScriptDispatcher$JavaScriptDispatcherTask.doCall(JavaScriptDispatcher.java:190)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.call(JavaScriptTask.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling this is due to the mismatched driver versions. Version [3.9](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/connection/ConnectionPoolSettings.Builder.html#maxWaitQueueSize-int-) has the method indicated in the error, but [4.2](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/connection/ConnectionPoolSettings.Builder.html) does not.

Once you get that sorted out, you are going to want to change this line

```js
var jsonDoc = JSON.stringify(connectorMessage.getEncodedData(msg));
```

to this

```js
var jsonDoc = connectorMessage.getEncodedData();
```

`msg` does not exist in a Javascript Writer, and `connectorMessage.getEncodedData()` does not take any parameters and returns a String. `connectorMessage` is an instance of `ImmutableConnectorMessage` from the Mirth User API.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to have been the driver version combinations.